# how do i calculate factorials in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, factorial

Does anybody know if there is an angularjs function to calculate factorials in angularJS? i can't seem to find any, and my own function doesn't work.

It would be nice if there is an existing one.

Comment: angular is javascript and there wouldn't likely be any specific angular method. Try a math library if your code isn't working although it shouldn't be hard to find what you need

Answer (score 1):

this is pure javascript, nothing to do with the Angular Framework

This is a recurvise factorial function (found over the web):

```
function factorial(num)
{
    // If the number is less than 0, reject it.
    if (num < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    // If the number is 0, its factorial is 1.
    else if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Otherwise, call this recursive procedure again.
    else {
        return (num * factorial(num - 1));
    }
}

var result = factorial(8);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter which would calculate factorial of give number, refer this [factorial plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/hpRXJfHvinBCJNL4ulHx/)